# Symfony addEventSubscriber gives null on Normalized Format instead of class object

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.5.9 and I have a strange problem on my code referring a FieldSubscriber passed into an EventSubscriber added to a Form.

Basically, the Form has several EventSubscriber to implement dynamic 'entity' fields. The fields are filled with objects from query_builders defined into the corresponding FieldSubscribers. Then, at validation time, the form should keep the final objects chosen by the user.

This implementation works fine but for a single EventSubscriber. In this case, the Symfony profiler raises an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8DSM.jpg .

This is the FieldSubscriber I pass to the EventSubscriber:

```
Class AddSecondChoiceFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $propertyPathToChoice;

public function __construct($propertyPathToChoice)
{
    $this->propertyPathToChoice = $propertyPathToChoice;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA  => 'preSetData',
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT    => 'preSubmit'
    );
}

private function addSchoolForm($form, $studyField, $stagePeriod)
{
    if($studyField){
        $formOptions = array(
            'class'         => 'A4UDataBundle:StageKind',
            'empty_value'   => 'Seconda scelta ...',
            'label'         => 'Seconda scelta per lo stage*',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use( $studyField, $stagePeriod) {
                return $er->getChoices($studyField, $stagePeriod);
                },
            'property' => 'nomeStage',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                )
        );
        $form->add($this->propertyPathToChoice, 'entity', $formOptions);
    }
    else {
        $formOptions = array(
           'label'  => 'Seconda scelta per lo stage*',
           'choices' => array("Seconda scelta..."),
           'attr' => array(
               'class' => 'form-control',
               )
        );
        $form->add($this->propertyPathToChoice, 'choice', $formOptions);
    }
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data1 = $event->getForm()->get('select_secondStudyField')->getData();
    $data2 = $event->getForm()->get('stagePeriod')->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $this->addSchoolForm($form, $data1, $data2);
}

public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $studyField = array_key_exists('select_secondStudyField', $data) ? $data['select_secondStudyField'] : null;
    $stagePeriod = array_key_exists('stagePeriod', $data) ? $data['stagePeriod'] : null;
    $this->addSchoolForm($form, $studyField, $stagePeriod);
}
}
```

and this is how I use it:

```
->addEventSubscriber(new AddSecondChoiceFieldSubscriber('selectSecondChoice'))
```

What is strange is that similar fields (built in the same way) do not have the same problem and passes the validation.
It is important to consider that the following code works (i.e. it passes the validation, even if it is not dynamic anymore):

```
        ->add('selectFirstChoice', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Campo di studi*',
        'class' => 'A4UDataBundle:StageKind',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('OS')
                        ->groupBy('OS.nomeStage');
            },
        'property' => 'nomeStage',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => 'Campo di studi'
            )
        ))
```